# Reuse Provide in Guice based on parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, guice

I've tried searching for this but haven't really found a solution so decided to post a question.

I'm working on an application where a user will input an IP (an SNMP device) and my application needs to connect to it and work with it. During runtime of the application, the user may provide another IP address and then I need to connect to the second one also keeping both the connections alive (as singletons).

My problem is I'm not able to wrap my head around this conceptually. My connection module is right now something like the following:

```
@Override
Configure() {
  String ip = first ip;
}

@Provides
Connect connect() {
  // connect to ip
  return connection;
}
```

Can anyone give me some hints here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pass the IP address as an argument for your Connect class constructor. You can then look at [FactoryModuleBuilder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) so that you can inject dependencies to your Connect class in your code. As for your requirement about singletons, I am not too sure of what you mean there. A singleton means, by definition, that there's only one instance of a class. Here, you want two (or possibly more). What I suspect is that you want at most a single Connect instance per IP String in the entire application. If that is the case, your factory needs to be a bit cleverer that the one created automatically by FactoryModuleBuilder. It could be a singleton itself and store an index (map? concurrent map? cache? It depends on your thread-safety requirements) of ip -> connect instances for those that have been already created.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back if it worked, but yes this is the requirement. I basically want to reuse connections and create a new one only if the IP is different. So, I will be using a Map to store currently connected devices.

Comment: The map itself should be a singleton: beware of thread safety.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer since this was what pushed me in the direction I wanted.